# How to remove header in list of figures, tables, and bibliography (book class)

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, page-numbering, books

I redefined how `chapter*` environment appears in `book` class as follows:

```
% CHAPTER* HEADER
\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
{%
    \vspace*{\@spacebeforechapterhead}%
    \parindent 0pt \Large%\bfseries
    %\phantom{\@chapapp}%
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \vspace*{\@spaceinchapterhead}%
    \rule{0.666\textwidth}{0.5pt}
    \par
    \vspace*{\@spaceinchapterhead}%
    \vspace*{\@spaceinchapterhead}%
    {\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}\hfill}%
    \mbox{}\par
    \mbox{}\par
    \mbox{}\par
    \pdfbookmark[0]{#1}{#1}
    \markright{}%remove header
}%
}
```

List of figures, List of tables, and Bibliography all use `chapter*` internally, but for some reason they keep the header, as shown below.

[image: header]

How can I remove the header in the mentioned three environments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would *not* modify the definition of `\chapter*`. Instead, simply change

```
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
```

to

```
\begingroup
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\endgroup
```

This ensures that the `plain` page style, which typesets the page number in the middle of the footer line, is in force for the output of `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures`, and `\listoftables`. The `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` statements serve to "localize" the scope of the `\pagestyle{plain}` directive.

---

*Addendum*: For the bibliiography, I suggest you employ the following coding eye:

```
\cleardoublepage
\begingroup
\pagestyle{plain}
\markboth{}{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} % optional
\bibliography{mylib} % if entries are in file 'mylib.bib'
\endgroup
```

This assumes that you have a suitable `\bibliographystyle` directive somewhere else in the document, along with all required `\cite` instructions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I have to redefine chapter* as I use it for other stuff too. Your solution did a trick for list of figures and tables (I used \markright{} instead of \pagestyle{}). However, it does not work for \bibliography. Any suggestions?

Comment: @MarkoGulin - Please advise how you create the bibliography: by hand, with BibTeX, with biblatex, or by some other method?

Comment: I'd say with BibTeX. I have a .bib file, and call in the document as `\bibliography(mylib.bib}`. I'm not using any additional packages.

Comment: One more thing: I'm using the `titlesec` package, maybe that has something to do with how bibliography appears.

Comment: @MarkoGulin - Please see the addendum I just posted.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick, although I used "myheadings" style to control how it appears. Question: Why did you use `markboth` directive, everything works fine even without that?

Comment: @MarkoGulin - I know next to nothing about the structure and contents of *your* document. In the quick-and-dirty sample `book` class document I cobbled together, it turned out to be necessary to insert `\markboth{}{}` to get rid of the left-over header information from the chapter prior to the bibliography. If that's not necessary for *your* document, more power to you.